# calculate duration spent in custom field status

Tags: custom-field, process-builder, field-history

We are trying to track the duration (time spent in days/hours) in each Status change (Custom Field) on the Opportunities Object. Right now we have enabled field history on this custom field (picklist) of status, but this reports into the Opportunity Field History related box (which shows changes made to anything altered in the Opportunity)

We need to only track the Change of Status on this picklist and how much time it spent total in that particular status, even if ie:status updated from prospecting to contract signed and back to prospecting---(similar to the history shown on 'Stage History'--

we need to calculate the overall time it spent in prospecting stage not a reset counter when it moved back. We do not have a developer to help us with some coding I imagine this would take, so I believe utilizing the Process Builder would help us accomplish this and if this is the way to go- confused on the steps to take.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The functionality that you are looking is not possible using Process Builder at this time. I believe it might be possible in the near future with enhancements that are coming in the next releases, but I cannot assure you of that.

You will have to rely on code in order to achieve it. I have some code that might help you.

Here is what you will need for the code:

1. Add field to Opportunity Object called "Last Status Change" (Date Time)
2. Add formula field (name it "Time in current Status") to Opportunity object with the following logic: IF(ISBLANK(Last_Status_Change__c), NOW() - CreatedDate, NOW()- Last_Status_Change__c)
3. Create a new Custom Object called "Opportunity Status Change"
4. Add the following fields to this new object:
   Opportunity (Lookup to Opportunity)
   Status (Text)
   Time in Status (Number)

Create the following trigger on the **Opportunity** Object:

```
 trigger trgOppTrackStatusTime on Opportunity (after update)  {
        Map<string,Opportunity_Status_Change__c> metricByKey = new Map<string,Opportunity_Status_Change__c>();

        for(Opportunity_Status_Change__c m : [SELECT id, Status__c, Opportunity__c, Time_In_Status__c FROM Opportunity_Status_Change__c WHERE Opportunity__c IN :trigger.newMap.keyset()])
        {
            metricByKey.put(string.valueOf(m.Opportunity__c)+string.valueOf(m.Status__c),m);
        }

        List<Opportunity_Status_Change__c> metrics = new List<Opportunity_Status_Change__c>();
        string key = '';
        Decimal hours;
        for(Opportunity o : trigger.new)
        {
            String oldStage = trigger.oldMap.get(o.Id).Operations_Status__c;
            String newStage = o.Operations_Status__c;
            Boolean stageChanged = oldStage != newStage;

            if(stageChanged)
            {
                hours = o.Time_in_current_Status__c;

                Opportunity_Status_Change__c temp;
                key = string.valueOf(o.Id)+string.valueOf(trigger.oldMap.get(o.Id).Operations_Status__c);
                if(metricByKey.containsKey(key))
                {
                    temp = metricByKey.get(key);
                    temp.Time_In_Status__c += hours;
                }
                else
                {
                    temp = new Opportunity_Status_Change__c(
Name=trigger.oldMap.get(o.Id).Operations_Status__c,
                                                Status__c = trigger.oldMap.get(o.Id).Operations_Status__c,
                                                Opportunity__c = o.Id,
                                                Time_In_Status__c = hours
                                             );
                }

                metrics.add(temp);
            }
        }

        if(metrics.size() > 0)
            upsert metrics; }
```

If the code fails to save, provide me the error and I will provide an update.

Good Luck!!

Comment: First off thank you for getting me started here--appreciate it! I have created everything you mentioned and am receiving an error on the Apex Trigger Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: '<' at line 1 column 8 
trigger <name> on Opportunity_Status_Change__c (<events>) {

}trigger trgOppTrackStatusTime on Opportunity (after update)  {
    Map<string,Opportunity_Status_Change__c> metricByKey = new Map<string,Opportunity_Status_Change__c>();

Comment: Hi JazzyJ, I think that the auto-generated code when you click the New Trigger button is the one thats erring out. Please make sure that the only code you put on the edit box is what I provided. If thats not the case, let me know and we can look into it further.

Comment: Thanks SlashApex you were correct on that first error!! But im getting another one now Error: Compile Error: Invalid field Status__c for SObject Opportunity at line 14 column 52 


Also will this coding show the overall duration spent in each status in days or hours (we need days)

Comment: Hi JazzyJ, it will show it in days. What is the APi name of the field that you want to track time for? I assumed it was called Status__c, but if that is not the case, then just replace Status__c with the correct name.

Comment: Sorry mate its not working for me. I tried replacing the Status_c with Operations_Status__c  on all lines I could find. I am getting errd Compile Error: Incorrect SObject type: Opportunity should be Opportunity_Status_Change__c at line 1 column 1 
trigger trgOppTrackStatusTime on Opportunity (after update)  {
    Map<string,Opportunity_Status_Change__c> metricByKey = new Map<string,Opportunity_Status_Change__c>();

    for(Opportunity_Status_Change__c m : [SELECT id, Status__c, Opportunity__c, Time_In_Status__c FROM Opportunity_Status_Change__c WHERE Opportunity__c IN :trigger.newMap.keyset()]

Comment: I made an update to the code with the new information about the Opportunity field being tracked. Please make sure that you are creating the trigger on the "Opportunity" object and not on the "Opportunity_Status_Change__c" object.

Comment: This new code did not send back any errors and took! But the process doesnt seem to be working. How can I attached screenshots to these posts?

Comment: I think you cannot add pics to comments, only on the original question. One other step you might need. Edit the page layout on the Opportunity, and add the related list for the new object Opportunity_Status_Change__c. If you do not see records coming in when you change the Operations_Status__c on the opportunity, then in fact, there must be something wrong with the code.

Comment: I added it to the original question, please see above for reference. The related list is there but the data it displays is not what we are looking for. We need it to act similarly to the Stage History related list; showing --Status, Total Time Spent in Status, Owner who Modified it

Comment: So, if the User A creates the Opp in status "New". User B changes it one day later to Status "In Progress" and then User C changes it one day later to Status "New" again. Finally User D sets the status to "Completed" one day later. What should show on the table. As I coded it, this is what should show:

Status  =  Time in Status (days)
---------------
New             =      2,                       
In Progress  =      1,
Completed   =       1

Comment: Could you provide the desired result for the scenario I presented?

Comment: So in your example scenario, History should show: Last Modified By Column 'User A'  Status Column 'New' Total Duration 2 days Last Modified by Column 'User B' Status Column 'In Progress' Duration 1 day etc..

Comment: Yep, seems like we agree on functionality. I think the confusion might be coming from the related list. Edit the page layout of the Opportunity. Once in edit mode, scroll down to the related list and hover over the related list header. Click on the little wrench. Once you do that, you can configure which columns to include on the related list. Select the status, time in status and last modified by fields. Let me know if that is closer to what you need.

Comment: I was testing the count on the stage duration by changing it back and forth to different stages, but received this error when trying to switch the stage the most recent time

Comment: Error:Apex trigger trgOppTrackStatusTime caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: trgOppTrackStatusTime: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0 with id a0Zg0000001ois5EAA; first error: INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, cannot specify Id in an insert call: [Id]: Trigger.trgOppTrackStatusTime: line 43, column 1

Comment: Change the last line from: insert metrics;      To:  upsert metrics;

Comment: rilliant mate! One last question please look at original post, I posted a snip of the related list. How can we change 'Opportunity Status Change Name' from displaying those random sequence of numbers and letters to the actual name of the stage –@slashApex

Comment: Hey JazzyJ, i made some changes to the code. The formatting is weird because i made it from the phone, but you can see what I added clearly.

Comment: The new code work perfectly except one thing! It does in fact change the name of the Opportunity Status Change Name to the actual name of the stage EXCEPT for the first stage change, the second and third stage change does show up properly. Please see original post for new picture posted for example